# Found elements in a string

Tags: jquery

Say I have this script

```
$.get('test.html', function(data){ 
    //data
});
```

How can I find a div with a specific class inside `data`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `data` as the context argument to [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), like this:

```
$.get('test.html', function(data){ 
   $("div.someClass", data)
});
```

Comment: alert($('div.someClass',data).html()) is working in chrome, but returning null in IE.

Comment: @tou - Is the HTML you're dealing with valid?

Comment: Well, it's a Sharepoint web page. Is .html() function nor supported in IE. Isn't JQuery supported in all major browsers??

Comment: @tou - If it's an entire webpage, you have have issues...it's reliant on creating a `documentFragment` which can vary between browsers if the content isn't valid for a `.innerHTML` call.   What does `$(data).html()` give you in IE?

Comment: $(data).html() gives me blank. alert(data) gives me the HTML markup of the web page. So, is there no way to do what I want in IE?

Comment: @tou - Not if it's invalid markup it won't tolerate, you can check it here:  http://validator.w3.org/